# Combine two html selections with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible two combine two html selections in jquery?

```
var derp1 = $('#derp1').html();
var derp2 = $('#derp2').html();

var combDerp = derp1.add(derp2);

$('#derpina').html(combDerp);
```

I want to show two certain parts of html into one and display them in another section of the page.  Any help is well appreciated :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are getting the html of each, you can just concatenate the two.

```
$('#derpina').html(derp1 + derp2);
```

Or, you can take the actual nodes and move them.

```
var derp1 = $("#derp1");
var derp2 = $("#derp2");

$("#derpina").html(derp1.add(derp2));
```

Comment: Yes of course!  Thanx @KevinB, when you put it that way I should have seen this sooner.  This worked perfectly, thanx again  :)

Comment: I think your example variable names fit nicely for this question... :)

Comment: Hehe, gotta lov the derps  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
var combDerp = derp1.add(derp2);
```

to

```
var combDerp = derp1 + derp2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate them.

```
var combDerp = derp1+derp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQuery .Append() if you are trying to append HTML.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: For the sake of semantics: You can’t "append" HTML strings. jQuery creates document fragments and appends DOM nodes behind the hood.

Comment: @David I stand corrected and appropriately so.  Having briefly read the API documentation I had an assumption as to how it would work. Reading your response I set out to prove myself correct and managed to do quite the opposite.  Thank you for setting it straight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elements to move, you should just use:

```
$('#derp1, #derp2').contents().appendTo('#derpina');
```

If you want to copy them, you should use:

```
$('#derp1, #derp2').contents().clone().appendTo('#derpina');
```