# combine two selections to query database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have a div which represents a category of items ...when I hover over the div a drop list of countries shows, then when the user selects a country....the items of that category of that country should be queried and retrieved from the database ...

Each category has it's own div(with the image inside). The countries are a list in a div.

I check some answers like this one ...but none fits for my case
[Combine two html selections with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369240/combine-two-html-selections-with-jquery)

My query should contain 2 fields ...when hover on Category need to pick its name , and country.

Trying a "form" didn't fit for this. Maybe JQuery or even React could handle this I hope...I've no clue in either one :)

Or maybe there is another approach!

P.S: I'm using spring boot 5, thyme leaf 3, Java and MySQL for DB.

Comment: Can you provide your code via Code Snippet?

Comment: @sugars ...hi, as I have mentioned I have no JQuery or React code to implement my requirement as I basically don't know both languages....